# Calculus question related to profit

Tags: integration

Marginal profit for certain item is given by $P\left(x\right)=\frac{200x+4000}{x^2+40x+1}$, where $x$ is the number of items made.  Find the total profit when $x$ items are made, and hence the profit from $5000$ items.

For the above question should I just integrate and then enter $5000$ for $x$.

Integration of the above equation will give $100\ln\left(x^2+40x+1\right)$

Comment: What is your question precisely?

Comment: I want to calculate the total profit when 5000 items are sold.  Does this include calculating constant C1 (obtained from integration) by applying boundary conditions?